# Listar todos los registros almacenados de mi clase python + django

Tags: python, django-views

He creado una view en python para mostrar especificamente un registro de mi base de datos  y elcódigo me funciona excelente (con este bloque de código se me muestra en el navegador el articulo donde el id = 1) es el siguiente:

```py
obj = Computer.objects.get(id=1)

    context = {
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, "Computers/computer_detail.html", context)
```

```html
{% block content %}

        <h1>{{ object.name }}</h1>
        <p>{{ object.serial }}</p>
        <p>{{ object.user_name }}</p>
        <p>{{ object.ip_address }}</p>


{% endblock content %}
```

Sin embargo si cambio el código para ver todos los registros en el navegador no me sale nada:

```py
obj = Computer.objects.all()

    context = {
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, "Computers/computer_detail.html", context)
```

```html
{% block content %}
     {%for control_var in context%}
        <h1>{{ object.name }}</h1>
        <p>{{ object.serial }}</p>
        <p>{{ object.user_name }}</p>
        <p>{{ object.ip_address }}</p>
     {% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

Que debería corregir para que me salgan todos los artículos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos lo que pasa es que estas tomando mal el contexto fijate que en tu views tienes asi:

```
obj = Computer.objects.all()
context = {
    'object': obj
}
```

si te fijas estas pasando **object** a tu template y asi debes recibirlo :

```
{% for objeto in object %}
  {{ objeto.name }}
  ..
  ..
{% endfor %}
```

con eso ya solucionarias tu problema..espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me ha funcionado perfectamente! Saludos.